# C/ C++ Linked List is never null

Tags: c++, c, list, pointers

I am currently working on a program that reads in numbers and adds them to a Linked List.

The problem I am having is that pointers to my struct are never null, hence I cannot use if-conditions without running into some sort of error (SIGSEGV).

In the main method, I create a struct node pointer, named "head":

```
struct node* head;
```

In the function push I would check if head is null - if it is, it means that it is uninitialized. I checked this with a normal if-condition:

```
if(head == null){
    //Code
}
```

This never worked, the if-condition was always skipped. To fix this, I introduced a initFlag (as seen below in push(...)) to make sure the list is initialized with a head before calling push again (thus appending a number). This worked, the first number has been successfully pushed. Now, however, I am again having issues with a if-condition and so running again into a SIGSEGV. The error is thrown here:

```
while(current->next != NULL){
            current = current->next;
}
```

Here is the code:

```
struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
};

void push(int value, struct node* head, bool *initFlag){
    if(!(*(initFlag))){
        head = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        head->value=value;
        head->next = NULL;
        *initFlag = 1;
    } else{
        struct node* current = head;
        while(current->next != NULL){
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        current->next->value = value;
        current->next->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: initialize head to NULL.

Comment: The signature of `push()` should be `void push(int value, struct node*& head, bool *initFlag){`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, but that would mean the question can no longer be "`C/C++`" :)

Comment: @StoryTeller There's no c/c++ language anyways.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, oh I concur, was my sarcasm not clear enough!? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It never worked because you didnt set `head = null`

Comment: Thanks. I guess a break would be in order.

Comment: your push is still broken since head is not being assigned correctly in the initial case.